# Convert to hash - Ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this extracted from a table

```
#<Section id: 12, name: "Seccion 1", created_at: "2018-07-24 15:06:34", updated_at: "2018-07-24 15:06:34", quotation_id: 62, order: 0>
```

but I want to convert it to hash

```
name_seccions.each do | section |
  section.quotation_id = event_current
  #Convert to hash
  puts section.inspect
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
section_hash = section.attributes
```